# Paused in another thread

Tags: android

Hello I am stucking in very weired issue. I have an app installed in every device.. Now I have tested the code in android 7.0 MI phone and Honor 6x (7.0) both phones are upgraded from 6.0 version. Now what is happening.. When I debug the code using MI phone phone the code is working fine .I am adding channels and when I begin the transaction of database and I tried the same code by using Honor 6x then it stucks and shows me the paused in another thread. I don't know actually what is happened and what is the issue. Can anyone please help me. I pasted the code below.

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {

                            if (serviceBinder.getService().registerChannel(channel, String.valueOf(dataProfile.user_id),ids)) {

                                // at this line debug shows paused in other thread //In android 7.0 honor6x
                                if(db!=null) db.addChannel(channel);
                                update(null);
                                for(int i=0;i<ids.size();i++){
                                    if(!ids.get(i).equals(username)){
                                        sendMsg(channel, ids.get(i),names.get(i));}
                                }
                            }
                            dismissProgress();
                        }
                    }).start();
```

Comment: Is this a [MCVE], or does this only occur when used along with other code? If this is indeed standalone, have you checked the docs of all the calls inside the `if` conditional for their thread safety status?